# How to catch opened event on a ComboBox with Dojo?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I want to know whether a combo box has been opened and call a function that displays an progress bar while it loads the data from a store. I've check the API but no I didn't find any suitable event for what I'm doing.

**EDIT**

What I want to do is start a progress bar while the combobox is populated from the store. I've created a widget with the combobox and the progress bar (a custom class) and "decorate" openDropDown function with aspect.before. This is the code I've written:

```
    postCreate: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        aspect.before(
            this.comboBox, 'openDropDown',
            lang.hitch(this, function(){
                this.progressBar.increase();
            })
        );
        on(
            this.comboBox,
            'search',
            lang.hitch(this.progressBar, 'decrease')
        );
    }
```

But it seems is not using the right progressBar object.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for something like an "onOpen" event.  as of Dojo 1.10 The Dijit/Combobox widget does not support an event like the one you are describing, however it does support a number of other events that might meet your requirements.

I recommend looking into the api for a list of possible events: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/

However the following code will create a custom "onOpen" event like what you are describing.  I've provided a jsfiddle which demos this new event

http://jsfiddle.net/kagant15/z4nvzy44/

```
var comboBox = new ComboBox({
    id: "stateSelect",
    name: "state",
    value: "California",
    store: stateStore,
    searchAttr: "name"
}, "stateSelect")

// grab the existing openDropDown method
var openDropDownFunction = comboBox.openDropDown;
newFunction = function(){
    topic.publish("openDropDown") // add the custom "openDropDown" event trigger
    return openDropDownFunction.apply(this);
}

// replace the old comBox method will our new function
comboBox.openDropDown = newFunction;

// Subscribe to the custom openDropDown event and do something when it fires
topic.subscribe("openDropDown", function(){
    console.log("Open Drop Down even trigger");
});
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but doesn't seems to work in my case. I edited the original question with more information.